# Download With IDM context menu disabled in Opera

Tags: windows-8.1, opera, context

The context menu items are gray and can not be clicked.

[image: Screenshot-1]

[image: Screenshot-2]

Reinstalling IDM, reinstalling IDM Extention, Reinstalling Opera nothing helped.
But the context menus are fine in Google Chrome.

How can I get them working?

My system is Windows 8.1 Pro x64.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem and I solved it as follows:

1. Go to **options** in IDM
2. Click **Add browser** button
3. Now add the exe file of opera browser
4. Click Ok
5. Now check your browser context menu, it will be working fine.